Posterior distribution for multivariate normal under Jeffrey’s prior (mu, Sigma unknown)
I am looking for a proof of the statement on p92 of Bayesian Data Analysis (Second Edition) by German, Carlin, Styern, Rubin (2003):
$\Sigma | y \sim \text{Inv-Wishart}_{n-1}(S)$
$\mu | \Sigma, y \sim N(\bar{y},\frac{\Sigma}{n})$
where $y|\mu,\Sigma \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$, $\mu \in \mathbf{R}^d$, $\Sigma \in \mathbf{R}^{d \times d}$, and we assume a non-informative prior $p(\mu,\Sigma) \propto |\Sigma|^{-(d+1)/2}$, and we have $n$ iid observations of $y_1,…,y_n$ of $y$.
I attempted to prove this:
Using Bayes’ theorem we have:
$p(\mu,\Sigma|y) \propto p(y|\mu,\Sigma).p(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $p(y|\mu,\Sigma)$ is the likelihood of the data and $p(\mu,\Sigma)$ is the prior.
Likelihood:
$p(y|\mu,\Sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^{d}p(y_i|\mu,\Sigma)\propto |\Sigma|^{-n/2} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^d{(y_i - \mu)’\Sigma^{-1}(y_i-\mu)} \right)$.
This gives the posterior as :
$p(\mu,\Sigma|y) \propto |\Sigma|^{-\frac{n+d+1}{2}} \exp\left({-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n{(y_i-\mu)’\Sigma^{-1}(y_i-\mu)}  }\right)$
with some simplifications (completing the square and properties of trace operator) we can rewrite this as:
$p(\mu,\Sigma|y) \propto |\Sigma|^{-\frac{n+d+1}{2}} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left( \Sigma^{-1} S \right) -\frac{n}{2}(\bar{y}-\mu)’\Sigma^{-1}(\bar{y}-\mu) \right)$
where $S$ is the sample covariance matrix $S=\sum_{i=1}^n{(y_i-\bar{y})(y_i}-\bar{y})’$.
We can now factorize the posterior into the product of the conditional distribution of $\mu|\Sigma$ and the marginal distribution of $\Sigma$, i.e. $p(\mu,\Sigma|y) =p(\mu|\Sigma,y).p(\Sigma|y)$. By inspection, we can see the marginal distribution of $\Sigma$ has the form of an inverse Wishart distribution, i.e.
$p(\Sigma|y) \propto |\Sigma|^{-\frac{n+d+1}{2}} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left( \Sigma^{-1} S \right) \right)$
and the remaining term of the posterior has ALMOST the form of a multivariate normal distribution, i.e. we would like to say:
$p(\mu|\Sigma,y) \propto |\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left( -\frac{n}{2}(\bar{y}-\mu)’\Sigma^{-1}(\bar{y}-\mu) \right)$
But we missing $|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ from the posterior expression - we already used up all the $|Sigma|$ available in the inverse Wishart distribution term!
Does anyone have a proof from a paper / book I could take a look at for this book’s statement or can offer a suggestion of where my logic has gone wrong?
Many thanks!
